# Pyyaml not reading (non-ascii) character correctly ("§")

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have the following file (`sample.yml`):

```
Key: §
```

When I try to read it with the following function:

```
import yaml

with open("sample.yml", "r") as f:
    file = yaml.safe_load(f)
```

the file is not read correctly: `print(file)` returns

```
{'Key': 'Â§'}
```

Even though I wanted to avoid escape sequences, are there such escape sequences that can be used in this case? Is there a way without them?

I also tried setting the `§` in singlequotes (`'§'`) or dobule quotes (`"§"`), however, this did not solve the problem. Also, using `yaml.load` instead of `yaml.safe_load`

I am using pyyaml v5.4.1

How can I read the yaml file correctly?

Comment: There's nothing special about `§`, the [section mark](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a7/index.htm). The output you posted though looks like what you'd get if you tried to *display* a UTF8 string as ASCII (Latin1 specifically). In this case, the UTF8 byte representation is `0xC2 0xA7`. In Latin 1 `0xA7` is the value of `§`. Either you aren't using Python 3, or your terminal isn't set to display UTF8 characters

Comment: In short, there's nothing to fix except the terminal's settings

Comment: in that case, `file["Key"] == "§"` should return `True`, because according to your post this should only be a terminal display issue. However, it returns `False`

Comment: "Special" only in the sense that "§" is non-ASCII...will edit that in the title

Comment: Which **specific** Python 3 version are you using? Right now, the default encoding for `open` is `utf8`. Up to a point though it was still using the system's default. If you use an older version, `open()` may be reading the file as ASCII

Comment: I am using I am using Python 3.7.7 (64bit)

Comment: You should pass the encoding explicitly to be certain. From [open's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open) `The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever locale.getpreferredencoding() returns)`.

Comment: that is very true...I was looking so much into to `yaml.safe_load` function, that I overlooked the `open` function. Thanks for the hint! Opening with `open("sample.yml", "r", encoding="utf-8")` solves the problem! If you want the reputation for the, you may post this as an answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the encoding explicitly to be certain:

```
with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

From [open's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open)

> The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever locale.getpreferredencoding() returns).

This is still true for 3.10 but could change in the future and become `utf-8`.

The output you posted though looks like what you'd get if you tried to read or display a UTF8 string as ASCII (Latin1 specifically). In this case, the UTF8 byte representation for `§` is 0xC2 0xA7. `0xA7`is the byte value in Latin1 too, so the character ends up appearing as `Â§`